# Do not repeat string more than once

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

In the database I have various dates stored like so:

```
ID| Dates
-----------------
1 | 23 April 2014
2 | 24 April 2014
3 | 25 April 2014
4 | 01 May 2014
5 | 02 May 2014
```

I managed to trim all the digits from the string with PHP which only leaves me with the month titles.

What I am trying to accomplish is to loop the months with a While loop and only show each month only once.

I want to achieve the following:

```
<h1>April<h1>
<p>23 April 2014</p>
<p>24 April 2014</p>
<p>25 April 2014</p>

<h1>May</h1>
<p>01 May 2014</p>
<p>02 May 2014</p>
```

So, what I actually want is to dynamically sort the months under its rightful tag
I hope somebody can help

Thank you

Comment: Why not make a query to `select distinct` dates?

Comment: Why are you not using `DATE` column types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are query ascending by date, you can achieve your requirement by following example:

```
<?php
$results = array();// your dataset
$month_name = array(); // empty array

foreach($results as $row){
    $this_month = date('M', strtotime($row['date_field']));
    if (!in_array($this_month, $month_name)) {
        $month_name[] = $this_month;
        echo "<h1>{$this_month}</h1>";
    }

    echo "<p>{$row['date_field']}</p>";
}
```

I believe there are more better solution can be possible (by change database data field as date instead of keep date as string), but from your current scenario, this solution I think perfect.

**`******EDIT******`**
Updated code base on your provided example:

```
$month_name = array();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // $record['date_field'] is your dates field of your database
    $this_month = date('M', strtotime($record['date_field']));
    if (!in_array($this_month, $month_name)) {
        $month_name[] = $this_month;
        echo "<h1>{$this_month}</h1>";
    }
    echo "<li> <a href='dates.php?ID=" . $record['ID'] . "'>";
    echo "<p><strong>" . $record['date'] . " | " . $record['timeStart'] . " - " . $record['timeEnd'] . "</strong></p>";
    echo "<p>" . $record['place'] . " - " . $record['provincie'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $record['kind'] . "</p>";
    echo "</a> </li>";
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am a little new to this. But i have a while loop as so:

$result = mysql_query($sql);
  
while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 
      
      echo "<li>
        <a href='dates.php?ID=".$record['ID']."'>";
      echo "<p><strong>".$record['date']." | ".$record['timeStart']." - ".$record['timeEnd']."</strong></p>";
      echo "<p>".$record['place']." - ".$record['provincie']."</p>";
      echo "<p>".$record['kind']."</p>";
      echo "</a>
       </li>";
  }

How do I combine your code with mind?